# Error al Iniciar aplicacion en SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Buenos dias a toda la comunidad para empezar soy nuevo en Spring Boot viendo tutoriales he querido hacer mi primer HolaMundo pero resulta que me sale el siguiente error al correr mi aplicacion.

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
at com.cruizg3.demoStart.DemoStartApplication.main(DemoStartApplication.java:9)
```

cabe señalar que he instalado java 13 y eclipse 2019.
Agradecere su pronta ayuda.

aqui mando el pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cruizg3</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoStart</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoStart</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>                
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: El warning que te manda es por las opciones con las que tienes configurada la JVM y dice que en futuras versiones de java ya no estarán disponibles, no tiene nada que ver con el error, ¿Podrías subir el código de tu clase DemoStartApplication? para que te podamos ayudar mejor..

Answer (score 0):

EL error indica que alguna de las clases o método  esta deprecado en la versión de java que estas usando, significa que ya no esta o cambio, de todas maneras en tu pom indica que estas usando java 8, revisa archivo de configuración de maven. me ha pasado que esta librería es la que he tenido que actualizar

import  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

saludos.

Comment: la verdad he vuelto a reinstalar el java 1.8 y persiste el problema ahora me arroja esto: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at com.cruizg.demosts.DemoStsApplication.main(DemoStsApplication.java:9)